# Astra dashboard warning engine light on. Can I check fuses randomly?

Tags: cel, fuse, warning-light

My Car Vauxhall Astra Club Twinport, Maual, Petrol, 1598cc, 56 plate is currently showing constant engine light, which means there is some fault, but the car works fine.
Using the petal test I got Error codes

- 013007
- 013500
- 014100
- 040062
- 044306
- 111206
- 111606
- 000000

I read few forums which says check the fuse first, but I am not sure which fuse. So I am planning to check every fuse by taking out and inspecting visually, while keeping the car off.

Two questions.

1. Am I OK to remove fuses randomly from the fuse box and check them?
2. From the error codes above could anyone tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: From a quick google search, check fuse 26 under the bonnet.  Should be a 10AMP fuse.

Comment: fuses are meant to be blown and thus removing them randomly should not cause any trouble unless you do not put it back according to their respective ratings

Comment: If your radio has an anti-theft lockout, be sure you have the code handy before you start randomly pulling fuses.  You might also loose all your radio presets and clock time, but those are just nuisance items...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a bit of googling there's a [forum page](http://www.vauxhallownersnetwork.co.uk/index.php?threads/1-6-sxi-fault-code-problem.259495/) which has many of the error codes listed:

```
ECN 13500 = O2 sensor 1 heater malfunction
ECN 14100 = o2 sensor 2 heater mulfunction
ECN 40062 = EGR valve
ECN 44306 = EVAP valve
ECN 111206 = Intake manifold air control fault
ECN 111606 = Thermostat malfunction
```

There's a suggestion that they are all tied to fuse 26 which is labelled "Engine Electronics" in the fuse layout on this [helpful page](http://fusesdiagram.com/opel-vauxhall/fuse-box-diagram-astra-h.html).

There are other engine electronics fuses listed, you should probably check those as well as any labeled ABS, it's fine to pull and check them (Use a multimeter if you can), I'd suggest you do it with the key out of the ignition entirely.

It's also possible that the fuse hasn't blown, but is making bad contact due to corrosion, so if the fuse is good try cleaning the contacts on the fuse and the fuse receptacle. Sometimes just taking the fuse out and re-inserting it a few times will clean it enough to work. If the fuse is blown replace it, if it blows again you've got a short circuit somewhere that needs to be investigated.

Comment: I google before where it said that check fuse 26, but When I checked the fuse box in the boot of my car, I found NO fuse in the slot of no. 26. After more research, I found that THERE ARE 2 FUSE BOXES. Another fuse box is under the bonnet. That's where the fuse 26 is and guess what it was broken and needs replacing. Thanks to all and hope this helps someone. I have now ordered a pack of car mini fuses.